# Concepts or methods of how to record invoices paid for manual payments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to devise a system for recording manual payments, such as Cheque, Chaps, Bacs.

What I am struggling with is how to connect the dots, between the time I leave the application and the time I come back on click confirm

I have an invoice table with 3 suppliers. Each 3 have different methods for of manual payments with a unique INVNO.

I come along today and decide I am going to make the payments, so I extract the invoices from the INVOICE table. 
I get a list of what needs to be paid.

```
1. CHEQUE 170 BT
2. CHAPS 300 VIRGIN
3. BACS 10 ORANGE
```

So I run along to the bank and make those payments and come back to my application to record which 3 payment covered which invoices.

I was hoping I enter the cheque payment has been made, at which point the payment is inserted into the PAYMENT table, the system will automatically assign a new PAYID, along with update the INVOICE table with the new PAYID to show INVNO>PAYID.

Problem so CHEQUE gets entered, new PAYID "1" is assigned, it then goes to INVOICE table and update rows 1,3,6 with the new PAYID.

Where I get lost, is when I enter the Payment and get a new ID, how do I recognize which INVNO the payment is referring to? Or am I completely going in the wrong way about doing this.

i'm confused how to link all 2 processes. Getting the list of invoices, confirming which invoices have been paid without manually specifying the INVNO as there could be hundreds to process

```
INVOICE TABLE
INVNO   MERCHANT    T   AMOUNT      METHOD
1       BT              100         CHEQUE
2       VIRGIN          200         CHAPS
3       BT              50          CHEQUE
4       ORANGE          10          BACS
5       VIRGIN          100         CHAPS
6       BT              20          CHEQUE

PAYMENT TABLE
PAYID   MERCHANT    T   AMOUNT
1       CHEQUE          170
2       CHAPS           300
3       BACS            10

INVOICE TABLE
INVNO   MERCHANT    T   AMOUNT      METHOD
1       BT          1   100         CHEQUE
2       VIRGIN      2   200         CHAPS
3       BT          1   50          CHEQUE
4       ORANGE      3   10          BACS
5       VIRGIN      2   100         CHAPS
6       BT          1   20          CHEQUE
```

Comment: Ok so after creating a new INVOICE_PAYMENT, how do I link the newly created payment, with which Invoices they are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

How about another table, let's call it `INVOICE_PAYMENT`, that consists of `(INVNO, PAYID)` pairs?  You can populate it just after you insert new entries into `PAYMENT`, which will no longer need an `AMOUNT` column (because that can be discovered by joining the tables and grouping); and neither of the existing tables will need a `T` column (because that can be discovered by joining with `INVOICE_PAYMENT`).

```sql
CREATE TABLE INVOICE_PAYMENT (
  INVNO BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PAYID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (INVNO, PAYID),
  FOREIGN KEY (INVNO) REFERENCES INVOICE (INVNO),
  FOREIGN KEY (PAYID) REFERENCES PAYMENT (PAYID)
);

ALTER TABLE INVOICE DROP COLUMN T;
ALTER TABLE PAYMENT DROP COLUMN T, DROP COLUMN AMOUNT;
```

Then, to create a payment:

```sql
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (MERCHANT) VALUES ('CHEQUE');
SET @pay_id := LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- or fetch into PHP via your API

INSERT INTO INVOICE_PAYMENT (INVNO, PAYID)
  SELECT INVNO, @pay_id FROM INVOICE WHERE METHOD = 'CHEQUE' AND ... ;
```

To fetch the details of a given payment, including the amount paid:

```sql
SELECT PAYMENT.*, SUM(INVOICE.AMOUNT)
FROM   INVOICE
  JOIN INVOICE_PAYMENT USING (INVID)
  JOIN PAYMENT         USING (PAYID)
WHERE  PAYID = ?
```

To fetch the details of a given invoice, including the payment:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   INVOICE
  JOIN INVOICE_PAYMENT USING (INVID)
  JOIN PAYMENT         USING (PAYID)
WHERE  INVID = ?
```

Comment: Hi can you explain, when you are inserting INVNO into INVOICE_PAYMENT, where are you getting the value for it to insert? I can only see you pulling up last_insert_id() for PAYID

Comment: correct me if I'm seeing this wrong. But this doesn't work does it. Because you still have to manually work out which invoices are being paid to be able to use the values to insert "INVNO" into INVOICE_PAYMENT. At which point do you have to manually know all INVNO numbers and Manually assign them to PAYID

Comment: @adamgouldie: What is your business logic?

Comment: Basically I have an invoice table. These are huge list of little sums. I pay them in one go "1 payment" in the bank or online. Since they have to be made manually, I need to be able to take that list, come back and say it has been paid. I will be able to record that "1 payment" has been made, and it will go and enter a new PAYID, take that PAYID and assign it to which invoices have been paid. So now I can view all payments using which method. Also if I want to know which invoices are related to the payment I can do that. Without having to manually get 500 INVNO values

Comment: There is this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13071/generating-invoices-and-tracking which seems they were trying to do the same thing. Link orders to invoices to payments and then back again. By only having to enter one payment value. But it means to manually select the payments and which invoices they cover.

Comment: @adamgouldie: So then you can express in some way the invoices that are to be paid in one go.  This would typically involve fetching something like "all unpaid invoices due to BT", marking some subset as approved, and then issuing payment for that subset.  Or do you simply want to approve/pay *all* unpaid invoices (the assumption presumably being that they only get entered into this table once they are approved)?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. How to achieve the above, any conept I think of doesn't work